# authenticate with user/password in azure apim

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-authentication

We currently have an set of on-premise .net WCF SOAP services that use ws-security username/password, so the username and password are supplied in the soap header and the wcf framework handles the authentication against active directory.

We are tasked with moving the services to cloud, while keeping the service contract intact so we don't break dependent systems.  Our plan is to import the wsdl into APIM to present the API as a SOAP service, but the backend will actually be a Rest Service that APIM will call.

We have an express route setup between on-prem and our azure tenant, and our on-prem active directory synchronizes to Azure AD.

Is it possible, via APIM policy and/or azure functions to set up a mechanism that can extract the username/password from the soap header and authenticate it against Azure AD, prior to APIM calling the backend API, and what would that look like?